# DB2 Use select count(*) in fetch first

Tags: db2, db2-luw

How can I use `Select Count(*)` in `Fetch First`
or will be another way to limit the result length.

**Table A**

| PK |
| --- |
| 1 |

**Table B**

| PK |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

```
WITH ALL_DATA AS
    (SELECT *
     FROM TABLE_A
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE B
    FETCH FIRST (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WITH ALL_DATA) ROWS ONLY
    )
```

I am expecting the first row with item 1 from Table B.
I am using DB2 LUW.

Comment: Could you edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output ?

Comment: Also add what platform and version of Db2 you are working with.  Db2 for IBM i will not allow it ; "fetch-row-count must not contain a scalar-fullselect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax could be slightly different.
You may enumerate the `B` rows first and use their number in the `WHERE` clause.

```
WITH ALL_DATA AS
    (SELECT *
     FROM (VALUES 1, 2) A (I)
    )
SELECT I
FROM 
(
    SELECT B.*, ROW_NUMBER () OVER () AS RN_
    FROM (VALUES 1, 2, 3) B (I)
)
WHERE RN_ <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ALL_DATA)
```

| I |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5FPulGO_)